# realm linking object returns null

Tags: android, realm

I have a model named `Item`. the model has linkingObjects to model `ItemModifier`. The Question is, why do I have to query for it to return a result ?

```kotlin
open class Item() : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""

    @LinkingObjects("item")
    val itemModifiers: RealmResults<ItemModifier>? = null
}
```

```kotlin
var item = Item()
item.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(itemModifier)

var itemModifier = ItemModifier()
itemModifier.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
itemModifier.item = item
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(itemModifier)

for (itemModifier in item.itemModifiers) { // this returns nullOrEmpty.
   Log.e("test", itemModifier.id)
}

queriedItem = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Item::class.java).equalTo("id", item.id).findFirst()!!

for (itemModifier in queriedItem.itemModifiers) { // this return itemModifier.
   Log.e("test", itemModifier.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I assume the first `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(itemModifier)` is a typo and should be `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item)`.

Having done this the item you created (an unmanaged object) has now been copied into the realm, *but the reference you hold is still to the unmanaged object*. This is why a look at its linking objects field gives you an empty list. Whereas, as you have shown, retrieving the *managed* object via query gives you the result you expect.

Note that according to the docs ([here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-io.realm.ImportFlag...-)), the `copyToRealmOrUpdate` method returns a reference to the managed object, so you could use that immediately and you should get the correct result. E.g.:

```
var item = Item()
item.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
val managedItem = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(item)

var itemModifier = ItemModifier()
itemModifier.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
itemModifier.item = managedItem
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(itemModifier)

for (itemModifier in managedItem.itemModifiers) { // this should now work.
   Log.e("test", itemModifier.id)
}
```